# How should we approach homework questions? — Comment aborder les questions de devoir?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality, answer-quality

What’s our community’s stance on how best to ask and answer homework questions?

I was prompted by [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6510/217). It clearly states that it’s homework, and explains the question clearly, but is asking a very specific (multiple-choice) question.

Most Stack Exchange sites have dealt with this and it is now our turn. What should we keep in mind when answering questions? How can homework questions best be asked?

---

Quelle est la position de notre communauté au sujet des questions sur les devoirs? Quelle est la meilleure façon de les poser et d’y répondre?

Cette interrogation a été suscitée par [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6510/217). Le demandeur énonce clairement qu’il s’agit d’une question de devoir, la question est bien expliquée, mais il s’agit d’une question très précise (à choix multiple, en fait).

La plupart des sites du réseau Stack Exchange ont réglé cette question, et c’est maintenant notre tour. À quoi devrions-nous penser lorsque nous répondons à ces questions? Quelle est la meilleure façon de poser ces questions?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think we should make homework questions special. As long as they are real questions and good questions. In any case the advice on asking and answering questions provided by [Kareen's answer](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/428/82) **are good** and should be remembered by everybody here. Especially those points: do your own research before asking, and if you found an answer by yourself ask and answer your own question, ask about specific problems, one problem per question and be wary of copypasta.

Now, for my opinion on this matter: as per [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange) (emphasis mine)

> Since Stack Overflow launched, we’ve been trying to explain that **it’s not just a Q&A platform**: it’s also a place where you can publish things that you’ve learned: recipes, FAQs, HOWTOs, walkthroughs, and even bits of product documentation, as long you format it as a question and answer.

The point of our questions and answers is not just to be useful to the OPs, hence, quoting [Robert](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/423/82)

> Keep in mind that **questions are here to help users well beyond the original author**.

I do see the point of not providing straight answers to the OP of a homework question, which is to help him to learn by himself, considering that hard-won knowledge is better used remembered. It is a good idea, there is no denying that.

But

1. Asking a *good* question here is already a token of good will and efforts made, this site is still a rather confidential place, but even if it does reach the popularity of Stack Overflow, one still has to make basic searches to reach it and to show some dedication to ask a proper question that is not closed as *too localized*.
2. Our answers, especially for this kind of question are usually and should always be well sourced, they serve as directions to references that the OP will probably use the next time if he is of good will (see 1.)
3. And that is my main point: even if providing straight answer might be a slight disservice to the OP, it might help countless users who are not trying to pry homework answers from ours. Of course you might argue that those would also be served by a clues-and-pointers answer, but then what is the point of providing real answers to non-homework questions?
4. What teachers might want or not want of their students is not our problem and I don't see why we should refrain of asking and answering questions and sharing knowledge to serve the dogma that searching answers on the web is bad and should be discouraged.

That said, I see one suggestion that might solve this issue and please everyone: we could indeed point the askers of such questions to the chat or give them some pointers and clues in the comment section and try to incite them to answer their own question with our help. This way the OP would have his answer, but not without efforts on his part and future readers would have a straight answer.

---

Je ne pense pas que traiter ces « questions de devoirs » différemment des autres soit une bonne idée. Tant que ce sont des vraies questions et des bonnes questions. À ce propos les [conseils de Kareen](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/428/82) sur comment poser une bonne question restent bons. En particulier, il est très fortement conseillé de faire ses propres recherches avant de poser une question, quitte à la poser quand même et y répondre soi-même si on a trouvé la réponse, une question devrait ne concerner qu'*un* problème *précis* et copier coller les réponses sans les comprendre n'est pas une bonne idée.

Mes raisons :  d'après [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange)

> Depuis l'origine de Stack Overflow, nous essayons d'expliquer que **ce n'est pas qu'un site de question-réponse**: c'est aussi un endroit où on peut partager ce qu'on a appris, que ce soit des recettes, des tutoriaux, des astuces… tant qu'on le présente sous forme de question-réponses.

Nos questions et nos réponses ne sont pas destinées qu'à servir l'[*original posteur*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1727/82), pour traduire [Robert](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/423/82)

> Gardez à l'esprit que **les questions sont là pour aider tout le monde, et pas seulement leur auteur**.

Je comprends bien en quoi ne pas donner de réponses directes à une question de devoirs peut inciter l'OP à faire ses propres recherches et apprendre par lui-même, donc éventuellement à apprendre *mieux*, partant du principe qu'on ne retient bien que ce qu'on a cherché. Je ne conteste absolument pas cette position.
Mais :

1. Poser une *bonne* question sur FSE, c'est déjà faire des efforts et montrer de la bonne volonté. Pour l'instant ce site reste confidentiel, mais même s'il atteint un jour la popularité de Stack Overflow, pour y arriver et poser une question suffisamment intéressante pour ne pas être fermée comme *too localized* il faut déjà avoir fait des recherches et avoir épuisé ses autres recours.
2. Nos réponses devraient être autant sourcées que possible, elle donnent donc de toute façon des indices et des sources pour la prochaine fois que l'interrogateur ou un futur lecteur se trouvera face à un problème similaire.
3. Et c'est là mon argument principal : même si répondre complètement à la question au lieu de se contenter de donner des indices peut ne pas rendre le meilleur service à l'OP, c'est probablement la meilleure façon d'aider les autres futurs visiteurs, qui eux ne se poseront pas la question pour des devoirs et préfèreront certainement une vraie réponse.
4. Ce que les enseignants attendent de leurs élèves ne nous regarde pas et ce n'est pas à nous de nous préoccuper de savoir si un questionneur était ou non autorisé à se servir de FSE pour ses devoirs.

Cela dit, il existe une solution qui regroupe à mon avis le meilleur des deux approches : face à une telle question, plutôt que de répondre, nous pourrions proposer au posteur de nous rejoindre [chez Cosette](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) pour l'aider ou 
lui donner quelques indices en commentaires en lui suggérant de répondre à sa propre question s'il trouve la réponse. Quitte à poster nous-même une réponse complète s'il ne le fait pas. Ainsi il aurait bien cherché sa réponse lui-même avec notre aide et le souci pédagogique est respecté mais les visiteurs futurs trouveront quand même une réponse complète.

Comment: If I may comment on your four points: 1. I would think that a question phrased as “Is X A or B?” is too localized vs “Why would X be A over B?”. 2. Sources are good, yes, but comprehensive explanations are better. 3. Obviously we want to give full-bodied answers to those questions. But straight answers to *specific* examples will be useless to other users with the same general problem but different examples. Once again, comprehensive explanations are better than "X is A" answers.

Comment: 4. I was not suggesting we should refrain from answering but reminding that it’s the asker’s responsibility to check first. I am not trying to “serve the dogma that searching answers on the web is bad and should be discouraged”. I am trying to serve the idea that intellectual honesty is good and should be encouraged.

Comment: Glad to see that we agree with each other.

Comment: I’m always glad when we agree, however I do have to point out that I believe homework questions generally tend to run into certain problems that guidelines about these questions and answers help avoid. The linked question may not have been problematic, but future questions might be. That is why so many of our sister sites about common school subjects (eg. CS, math, English, physics, chemistry) have such guidelines. My answer was based on some of those guidelines that were necessary and took years to perfect. It is a CW, so you, or anyone, can edit it if you think it needs some improvement.

Comment: “tend to run into certain problems”: which ones if I may ask?

Comment: People frequently fail to do one of the things in bold in my answer. It hasn't happened here yet, but it may and probably one day will. We don't need to reach SO-level traffic for it. For example, people making fun of others or being condescending would sadly be unsurprising, and [teachers can even come around asking questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2012). There is also the impulse to simply give out the answer without much explanation, especially on more basic questions, and that reduces quality.

Comment: These issues have nothing to do with homework. They are only a matter of asking and answering according to the general site policy and to be civil with each other. Speaking about [maths.se], I found [an answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1661/15102) there that perfectly summarize my views.

Comment: I feel we are going off-track here. This is not about whether we should allow homework questions or not - *I never questioned that*. It's about trying to find ways to maximize their value for us and for the students while avoiding problems that yes can be found in other questions but are more common in homework-related ones. To have general guidelines to point people to. I will edit my answer to make what I'm trying to convey clearer. That we should prioritize comprehensive explanations as answers, but answering the specific homework question *alongside* explanations when constructive is fine.

Comment: I feel on-track, what I am trying to say is **we should not treat them differently** and **I don't want hints-only answers**. So the only policy I want for asking and answering these questions is **do what you would have done if it wasn't homework**, and this implies **point the OP to the chat if he doesn't want a full answer but justs hints**.

Comment: Please read my edited answer. "Hints" may have been a poorly chosen word to try to say that I simply advocate for making an extra effort to include explanations in homework questions and not just one-liner answers as have been seen (and accepted) in other questions. In general, no, they should not be treated differently, but I think they should be treated with extra care, and my answer is just guidelines, or a sort of checklist, for that extra care. Now that is my answer, I think it's good to have a clear faq for future reference. You don't, and I'm done arguing.

Answer (score 5):

The philosophy for asking and answering is the same as for all other questions and answer, but there are some specific things that tend to come up more frequently with homework questions.

These guidelines are based on the [English Language & Usage homework guidelines](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/346/9839), which in turn were based on the one from Stack Overflow, which took shape through years of experience. The guiding principles are that it’s okay to ask homework questions, but that our goal is to teach, not just to do people’s homework.

## Asking Questions

**Try to find the answer yourself first, and tell us what you’ve come up with.** Not only is this good for you learning, it helps us understand where you’re coming from, and provide answers that explain what you need to know!

**Ask about specific problems, not a whole assignment.** We’re trying to help you learn, not do your homework for you, so ask about the things you need help learning! Besides, our site is all about specific Q&A, not broad questions - specific questions get better answers.

**Tell us it’s a homework question.** If you don’t do this, you may not get great answers, and people may even think you’re trying to cheat.

**Make sure asking for help is allowed by your teacher and school.** We want to help, but not if it’s against the rules!

**Don’t directly copy our answers and turn them in.** Plagiarism is always bad, and besides, you won’t learn much that way.

## Answering Questions

**Focus on providing explanation; give specific answers if you feel it's helpful.** For example, if someone asks "In these sentences, do we use *bon* or *bien*?", say "We use *bon* in these situations and *bien* in these." and if you feel it's helpful, add "So the first is *bon*, the second is *bien*, the third...". We want to help people understand, and learn to answer these questions themselves. The explanation is the important thing; sometimes it may be good to let students use it to figure out the answers to the specific cases, and sometimes it may be best to just directly state the answer. But an answer without an explanation helps no one. Be careful to not only give out hints - answers should still answer the question.

**Be helpful and polite.** You probably know a lot more than the student asking the question. Never act like it’s a stupid question, or make fun of their mistakes. Don’t downvote their question just because you’ve known the answer since you were 6.

**Help others provide good answers.** Not everyone will have read these guidelines. If for example you see an answer which doesn’t explain anything, as usual, you can comment and suggest edits to improve it.

Finally, a side note: don’t use tags to mark questions as homework questions. Just noting it in the question is good!

---

La philosophie des questions et des réponses est la même que pour toutes les autres questions et réponses, mais certains points particuliers ont tendance à faire surface plus fréquemment dans les questions de devoirs.

Ces lignes directrices sont fondées sur la [politique des devoirs de English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/346/9839), qui a été fondée sur celle de Stack Overflow, elle-même façonnée par des années d’expérience. Ces lignes directrices indiquent que les questions sur les devoirs sont admises, mais que notre but premier est d’enseigner, non pas de simplement faire les devoirs des autres.

## Poser les questions

**Essayez de trouver la réponse vous-même et dites-nous ce que vous avez trouvé.** Cette démarche n’est pas seulement bonne pour votre apprentissage, elle nous aide également à comprendre votre cheminement et à vous donner des réponses qui expliquent ce dont vous devez savoir!

**Demandez à propos d’un problème précis au lieu d’un devoir complet.** Nous voulons vous aider à apprendre, pas faire vos devoirs à votre place. Demandez donc à propos de ce que vous avez besoin d’aide à comprendre! Notre site en est d’ailleurs un de questions–réponses, pas de questions trop générales. Les questions précises obtiennent de meilleures réponses.

**Dites qu’il s’agit d’une question de devoir.** Si vous ne le faites pas, vous n’aurez peut-être pas de réponses géniales, et certaines personnes pourraient même penser que vous tenter de tricher.

**Assurez-vous que demander de l’aide est permis par votre enseignant et votre école.** Nous voulons vous aider, mais pas si c’est à l’encontre des réglements!

**Ne copiez pas directement nos réponses avant de les remettre à l’enseignant.** Plagier n’est jamais bien, et vous n’apprendrez d’ailleurs pas beaucoup de cette façon.

## Répondre aux questions

**Misez sur des explications, donnez une réponse plus particulière si vous le jugez utile.** Si, par exemple, quelqu'un demande « Dans les phrases suivantes, doit-on utiliser *bon* ou *bien*? », dites « On utilise *bon* dans ces situations-ci et *bien* dans celles-là. » et si vous le jugez utile, ajoutez « Il faut donc utiliser *bon* dans la première phrase, *bien* dans la deuxième, et dans la troisième... ». Nous voulons aider les personnes à comprendre et à apprendre à répondre à ces questions elles-mêmes. L'explication est ce qui est le plus important. Quelques fois il vaut mieux laisser l'élève l'utiliser pour trouver les réponses aux cas particuliers, et d'autres fois il vaut mieux donner la réponse. Mais une réponse sans explication n'aide personne. Faites attention de ne pas donner que des indices – les réponses doivent toujours répondre à la question.

**Soyez utile et poli.** Vous en savez probablement beaucoup plus que la personne qui pose la question. *Jamais* ne devriez-vous suggérer que la question est stupide ou vous moquez des erreurs de la personne. Ne donnez pas un vote négatif à la question simplement parce que vous connaissez la réponse depuis l’âge de 6 ans.

**Aidez les autres à donner de bonnes réponses.** Ces lignes directrices ne seront pas lues par tous. Si vous voyez une réponse qui n’explique rien, vous pouvez comme toujours laisser un commentaire et suggérer des modifications pour l’améliorer.

Enfin, une remarque: n’utilisez par de tags pour marquer les questions comme questions de devoir. Une note dans la question est suffisante!