# Dit-on vraiment "générer le sens" ?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, editing

Le titre de plusieurs questions est "Comment X génère-t-il le sens de Y ?"

A ma connaissance, "générer" est un anglicisme pour engendrer, et de toute façon "Comment X engendre-t-il le sens de Y" est assez moche aussi. Je pense que j'aurais plutôt écrit "Comment X a-t-il fini par signifier Y" par exemple.

Pensez-vus qu'il faut les corriger, ou est-ce moi qui suis à côté de la plaque (ce qui est possible) ?

Comment: Oui, je suis tout à fait d'accord avec vous. C'est un anglicisme de la pire espèce. En bon français on dirait engendrer le sens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seules trois questions [répondent à cette description](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ag%C3%A9n%C3%A8re) : [1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20049/comment-bien-que-g%c3%a9n%c3%a8re-t-il-le-sens-de-quoique) [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26708/comment-serait-ce-g%c3%a9n%c3%a8re-t-il-le-sens-de-m%c3%aame) [3](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26710/comment-pour-tant-c-%c3%a0-d-pourtant-g%c3%a9n%c3%a8re-t-il-le-sens-de-n%c3%a9anmo). Elles ont toutes le meme auteur.

La formulation n'est effectivement pas idiomatique. Il s'agit d'une erreur commise par un contributeur en particulier, dont le français n'est pas la langue maternelle.

[Vous êtes encouragé à corriger ce genre d'erreurs](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/fix-typos-in-learner-question-corriger-les-fautes-dans-une-question-dapprenan). De nombreux apprenants fréquentent ce site, il est donc important de leur montrer du français exemplaire. Corriger les fautes ou les tournures non idiomatiques est un bon moyen d'apprendre. Attention seulement à ne pas trop en faire :

- Ne jamais changer ce qui est l'objet de la question. Si la question cite une phrase avec des fautes d'orthographe, par exemple, ces fautes font peut-être partie de ce que la personne qui pose la question ne comprend pas. S'il y a des corrections à apporter, il faut le faire en répondant à la question. Si les fautes sont sans lien apparent avec l'objet de la question, il vaut mieux poser un commentaire qui les explique, et laisser à l'auteur de la question le soin d'éditer la question.
- Merci de ne pas entrer dans une guerre civile sur le style ou le vocabulaire. Autant les fautes de grammaire ou d'orthographe et les phrases difficiles à comprendre sont à éviter, autant il n'y a pas de mal à avoir quelques tournures légèrement maladroites dans une question. De plus, merci de garder à l'esprit qu'il existe plusieurs variantes du français ; ce qui est bizarre pour un Tourangeau est peut-être parfaitement normal pour un Québecois.

Dans ce cas, la tournure est étrange, mais compréhensible. Je pense que c'est pour cela que personne n'a modifié ces titres. Cela dit ce serait une bonne idée de le faire. Il est particulièrement important d'avoir des titres faciles à comprendre (y compris pour un locuteur non natif, qui n'a pas forcément la même langue maternelle que la personne qui a posé la question et qui aura donc tendance à faire des erreurs différentes et à ne pas confondre les même faux amis). Les titres doivent aussi être facilement trouvables et repérables dans une recherche. Ils sont le premier point de contact avec une question.

Comment: Oui,je comprends ce que vous dites, mais il existe des situations oú la correction d'une phrase (et je ne parle pas de fautes d'ortographe) n'as pas été acceptée et a donne lieu a un tas de commentaires assez méchants à mon égard. Je ne prétend nullement est locuteur natif. Par contre, j'ai quand même un niveau avancé, pour le dire ainsi, et je trouve que les francophones et leurs "ami(e)s" parfois manque de doigté. L'autre question, il n'y a pas si longtemps, c'était que arriver/passer avec en et là etc. étaient interchangeables....L'univers parait être à l'envers.

Comment: Je vois souvent des erreurs sémantiques ou de structure de phrase, et si je ne m'exprime dans un français encore plus parfait que les francophones, on me tombe dessus, et la partie principale d'une question est laissée sans réponse, voire, sans commentaire. Et parfois, on essaie de corriger mon anglais.....:)

Comment: Par exemple: j'ai trouvé une phrase bancale dans une question. J'essaie de comprendre, et je note ce qui me semble ne pas aller. Et on vient de me dire cedi: @Lambie. Le temps du verbe n'importe pas du tout pour comprendre la question. Et par ailleurs, même si la situation décrite n'est pas vraiment habituelle, la phrase est complètement correcte. Laisse donc les gens en paix. – Stéphane Gimenez♦ 11 mins ago

Comment: Si une question est bâti sur un truc qu'un français ne ***dirait*** pas ou qui choque, vous trouvez normale qu'on me dise une chose pareille? Pardonnez-moi, mais ce n'est pas ma ***faute*** d'avoir plus de connaissances du/en français qu'un ou qu'une autre anglophone.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne comprends pas où vous voulez en venir. Je ne sais pas de quelle « chose pareille » vous parlez. J'ai bien remarqué que vous avez tendance à être très prescriptif, même quand un autre français dirait sans sourciller ce qui vous choque. Par contre, en parlant du loup, je comprends chaque phrase malgré quelques fautes d'orthographe (attention aux accords) et quelques tournures non idiomatiques (« c'est le monde à l'envers »). Je vous invite en tout cas à vous ouvrir plus aux remarques que les gens vous font. Ni votre français ni votre anglais ne sont parfaits, comme tout le monde.

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas d'être parfait ni de perfection. "Une chose pareille" va avec le commentaire qui m'ai été fait par Stéphane au paragraphe antérieur. J'ai signalé une phrase avec une structure bancale dans le forum, et lui m'a fait ces remarques-lá. //Et je trouve que vous êtes vraiment pas très gentil avec moi ici. J'essaie désésperément de communiquer avec vous, de vous faire comprendre une IDEE et ***la moitié de votre dernier commentaire*** est axé sur une critique de mon français ! "C'est le monde à l'envers" est complètement idiomatique en français !

Comment: Je suis interprète, et je ne traduit pas vers le français écrit, ce qui explique les fautes d'orthographe. Me dire que vous me comprenez "malgré les quelques fautes d''orthographe, et je-ne-sais-quoi d'autre est une insulte. Comme si ce que j'écris venait d'une personne analfabète. Une chose est certaine: mon français est mille fois supérieure à l'anglais que je vois écrit ici par des francophones. Too bad it was so impossible to have a conversation with you and you just repeat the same things without even trying to understand one little thing I was trying to communicate to you.